# How to set the 1st paragraph indentation...and space

Tags: memoir

I have been editing a book using memoir...and saw this ..

Every 1st paragraph in every chapter simply doesn't have indentation, so I managed to include `\paragraph{}` in every chapter...so far, so good....but I checked the spaces...and the 1st paragraph indentation is smaller than the following paragraphs..please, check the picture...the red arrow...

[image: Attention to the different indentation in red]

Is there a way to set the `\paragraph{}` spacing to be the same size as the following paragraphs?

I acknowledge that maybe there are more than one solution, e.g.: Changing every first chapter to start with a paragraph automatically... 
And also, I don't understand why it does not set the 1st paragraph indentation automatically.

Comment: Not exactly, but very hepful and solved 1 of my 2 problems. Thanks again Werner.
Now I just need to know how to have a bigger space between the ending and the beginning of a paragraph.

Comment: It's best to ask single questions within a post. That way half-answers like the duplicate can be avoided. Can you rephrase your question to contain your *single* current hurdle?

Comment: Do you mean another post the 2nd question and edit this one as a single question?
I can do that, no problem.

Comment: @Adriano - yes.

Comment: There you go, it's done. This question has been answered.

Comment: It is traditional that the first paragraph after a heading is not indented (try `texdoc memdesign`) for remarks on this. If you must do it then you should indent all first paragraphs after headings (e.g., after `\section`, `\subsection`, etc.). I won't tell you how to do it.